Understanding Promise chaining in PHP
I found this piece of code in a Github PR that aims at adding the Redis Sentinel support to a Redis client. (Redis sentinel is a service that will frequently check the state of multiple redis, and return the (redis) master's IP.
I'm not an expert in PHP, so, I really don't understand how it works, even though it seems to work correctly.
    public function masterAddress(): PromiseInterface
    {
        $chain = reject(new \RuntimeException('Initial reject promise'));
        foreach ($this->urls as $url) {
            $chain = $chain->then(function ($masterUrl) {
                return $masterUrl;
            }, function () use ($url) {
                return $this->onError($url);
            });
        }

        return $chain;
    }

In this code:

$this->urls are the different redis sentinel's urls
$masterAddress (which is returned from the promise) is the master's url
By calling $this->masterAddress() I get the master's URL

I don't even understand how it could return an URL since the $url variable isn't even used, so, how the chain could be anything else than just a chain having a "reject".

Then() expects two functions. 1) resolve 2) reject. So the Promise does not return $url, but the use keywords makes it possible for the anonymous function to access $url.

Yes, I agree with that, the "use" keyword allows to use it in the "onError" callback, but then, how is it possible that this piece of code returns a masterUrl when it doesn't even use the $url (redis sentinel URL) to get it?

Oh ok, I got it. The onError function is a custom function that will do all the work
